# Submit with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var email = $('#email');
var email_match = $('#email_match');
var fields = $('.registerForm');
var registerForm = $('#registerForm');

registerForm.on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   error = false;
    fields.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0 || $(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).addClass('error');
            error = true ;
        }
    });
    if (!error) {       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "{'email':" + email.val() + ",'email_match':" + email_match.val() + "}",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

On console.log(data)  i get the whole index page of the register file, why does this happend while i have specific calls in the data: section.

I only need it's values for later to insert it into the database how do i get only the values.

And is the way i'm working with the error handlers correct ?

Comment: You are posting to the same page you are making a call from. On top of the page you should have PHP handle the ajax call and then return something that you need as a result and then after call die(). that will stop it from dumping the entire page into the ajax result.

Comment: Where is "url" of ajax?

Comment: also i dont think you need $(this).val() == 0 in there.

Comment: You could use `serialize()` on your form element to save you from building the data object manually, and save some selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a url on the ajax call function

```
$.ajax({
            url:'the url you are posting too',
            type: "POST",
            data: "{'email':" + email.val() + ",'email_match':" + email_match.val() + "}",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you edit your post how to retrieve data whenever i use url, i tried `url: 'test.php'` and in test.php i did `echo $_POST['email']`.

Comment: where is test.php located, whats the full url and also please make this change
data: {'email': email.val(),'email_match': email_match.val() }

Comment: Ahaa, thanks! I get it now, on submit it send to test.php > this gives `$_POST['email']` > than on `success` i callback the data and i get the value. So i can now directly update from test.php to database! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Yep, but dont forget this change
data: {'email': email.val(),'email_match': email_match.val() }